# PHP-DOMDocument Character Encoding Issue

Tags: php, xml, character-encoding, domdocument

This one has been baffling me for a few days.  I'm having issues with character encoding, and I've spent much time researching and reading through Stack Overflow questions, and I am yet to find a solution.

So I have an XML file, and inside that file there is a group of tags similar to this:

```
<item name="purchase" date="November 12 2014 02:27:48">
  <airline>Aero Test Ltd</airline>
  <aircraft>Boeing 747-400</aircraft>
  <engine>Rolls-Royce RB211-524H2-T</engine>
  <config>5 25 40 560</config>
  <value>261430000</value>
  <name>None</name>
</item>
```

From a web page, a user can change the name of the aircraft (The `<name>` Tag).  The name is sent via XMLHttpRequest to my PHP page, which should create a new set of tags like the above, and log the name in a mySQL database.

It works normally with regular English-alphabet text.  When I try to use the name "`Corvina Panameña`" I come across some trouble with the `ñ`.

It adds this group of tags to my XML document (like it should):

```
<item name="renaming" date="January 03 2015 04:34:38">
  <airline>Aero Test Ltd</airline>
  <aircraft>Boeing 747-400</aircraft>
  <engine>Rolls-Royce RB211-524H2-T</engine>
  <config>5 25 40 560</config>
  <value>227852883</value>
  <name>Corvina Paname&#xF1;a</name>
</item>
```

And DOMDocument encodes the `ñ` as `&#xF1`, which is what it should do according to my research.  When I open the file in chrome it displays the character.

I have 3 other web pages, 2 of which use the data from the data from the mySQL database.  One of these mySQL-data pages displays the character, and then the problem: the other shows this character-combination instead: `Ã±`.  Both pages have the HTML5 Doctype and do not have a character set defined in a `<meta>` tag.

The 3rd web page uses the XML data.  Strangely, it displays the same character-combination as the 2nd mySQL page: `Ã±`. The page uses the HTML5 Doctype and does not have a character set defined in a `<meta>` tag.

What is the solution to this bizarre problem?

Is the problem similar to this:
http://www.glenscott.co.uk/blog/html5-character-encodings-and-domdocument-loadhtml-and-loadhtmlfile/

This is my DOMDocument procedure for adding the tag group: http://codepad.org/dHdiY5wG

DOMDocument procedure for reading the data: http://codepad.org/ATpkZq4H

Full XML File: http://codepad.org/XnN9ahuc

Screenshots: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jU7pH.jpg

**-Edit-**

`ini_set("default_encoding", "UTF-8")` and `htmlentities` didn't help.

**-Edit 2-**

Using `utf_encode()` on the data didn't help either.

**-Edit 3-**

It appears as if the post data being sent by the XMLHttpRequest is the problem, not the XML.

This data is sent: `Corvina Panameña`
And this is received: `Corvina Paname&Atilde;&plusmn;a`

Answer (score 0):

Try using `$xml = new DomDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');` to set the UTF-8 charset encoding for your xml file, if it isn't enough, try using `utf8_encode` with the name string prior to adding it to the xml doc.

Comment: This is the result of your solutions: `<name> Corvina Paname&Atilde;&plusmn;a</name>`.